# Probability, covariance, joint density

Tags: probability, covariance, joint-distribution

Let $f(x, y) =3\min(x,y)$ if x and y are values between $0$ and $1$. 
Find $\operatorname{cov}(x, y)$.

Is the right way to solve it, finding the marginal density of $x$ and $y$? And then the expected values? Or is there any other simpler way?

Comment: You cannot find covariance from the marginal densities; you need the joint density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to find directly $E[XY]$ and $E[X]=E[Y]$ (due to symmetry), the joint density is a simple function if you consider $y<x$ and $y>x$ cases separately: $$E[XY]=\int_{0}^1\int_0^x (xy)(3y)dydx+\int_0^1\int_x^1(xy)(3x)dydx$$
Execute the same integral by replacing $xy$ to $x$ or $y$ to find $E[X]=E[Y]$, and then you've the covariance.